# Cannot create session bean after switching to SDN4.1

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4

I am happy that SDN4.1 is now available, because version 4 was rather unstable. I have upgraded my project as soon as possible, but I have a strange problem which appears when, a method that uses Neo4j database connection is used. I see such exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/tsg] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.getSession' defined in package.config.ApplicationConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session]: Factory method 'getSession' threw exception; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver] with root cause
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.loadDriver(Components.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.driver(Components.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.openSession(SessionFactory.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.getSession(Neo4jConfiguration.java:56)
    at package.config.ApplicationConfig.getSession(ApplicationConfig.java:255)
    at package.config.ApplicationConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5bc6b7bf.CGLIB$getSession$15(<generated>)
```

I believe that this is a configuration problem, so here is my config:

```
package package.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.Neo4jServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.RemoteServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;


import package.controller.DeviceController;
import package.controller.PersonController;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package", excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = { DeviceController.class,
                PersonController.class }) })

@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package.persistence")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("package.neo4jrepository")
@Import({ WebSpringConfig.class })
public class ApplicationConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public ApplicationConfig() {
    }
    @Bean
    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
       Configuration config = new Configuration();
       config
           .driverConfiguration()
           .setDriverClassName
            ("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver").setURI("http://xxx:yyy@localhost:7474");
       return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("database.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer initializeDatabase() {
        DataSourceInitializer dbInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dbInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
        dbInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        dbInitializer.setEnabled(true);
        return dbInitializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resDatabasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        resDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("importagreements.sql"));
        resDatabasePopulator.setSqlScriptEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resDatabasePopulator;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "package.persistence.domain" });
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        jpaProperties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.bytecode.provider", "javassist");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "50");

        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager(Neo4jTransactionManager neoTransactionManager,
            JpaTransactionManager mysqlTransactioNmanager) throws Exception {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(mysqlTransactioNmanager, neoTransactionManager);
    }

    @Bean(name = "neo4jTransactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public Neo4jTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager(Session session) throws Exception {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(session);
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlTransactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public JpaTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory)
            throws Exception {
        JpaTransactionManager mysqlTransactioNmanager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return mysqlTransactioNmanager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50000000);
        return commonsMultipartResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(),"package.domain", "package.relation", "package.util",
                "package.httpBody");

    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }

}
```

Here is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>tsg</artifactId>
    <name>tsg</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>

        <!-- Web -->
        <javax.servlet.version>2.5</javax.servlet.version>
        <javax.servlet.jsp.version>2.1</javax.servlet.jsp.version>
        <javax.servlet.jstl.version>1.2</javax.servlet.jstl.version>
        <jersey.version>1.8</jersey.version>
        <com.google.code.gson.version>2.2.4</com.google.code.gson.version>
        <javax.ws.rs-api.version>2.0</javax.ws.rs-api.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.9.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <spring-security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring-data-commons.version>1.12.0.M1</spring-data-commons.version>
        <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.1.0.M1</spring-data-neo4j.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>

        <!-- Aspects -->
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>

        <!-- Neo4j -->
        <org.neo4j.app.version>2.0.3</org.neo4j.app.version>
        <neo4j.ogm.version>2.0.0-M2</neo4j.ogm.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <org.hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</org.hibernate.version>
        <org.hibernate-validator.version>5.1.1.Final</org.hibernate-validator.version>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.34</mysql-connector-java.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <junit.version>4.7</junit.version>

        <!-- Maven plugin -->
        <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.9</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.2.1</exec-maven-plugin.version>

        <!-- Smack -->
        <smack.version>4.1.0</smack.version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-snapshot</id>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        <name>Springframework Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
            <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>javax.validation</groupId> <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version> </dependency -->

        <!-- Smack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-java7</artifactId>
            <version>${smack.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
            <version>${smack.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-im</artifactId>
            <version>${smack.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${smack.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring-data-commons.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ******* JPA/Hibernate ******** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- additional libraries -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        </dependency>  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${com.google.code.gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <!-- Placeholders that are found from the files located in the configured 
                resource directories are replaced with the property values found from the 
                profile specific configuration file. -->
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <filters>
            <!-- Ensures that the config.properties file is always loaded from the 
                configuration directory of the active Maven profile. -->
            <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
        </filters>

    </build>

</project>
```

[image: Dependency Hierarchy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config looks correct. I had same issue upgrading over the weekend. I think the `ServiceNotFoundException` means you're You are probably still importing 1.x.x version of neo4j-ogm jar (post your pom config?). You should explicitly remove it from your pom.

```
<!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
 -->
```

Make sure you are bringing in the new `2.x.x` neo4j-ogm`-api` neo4j-ogm`-core` jars. Also make sure you are using spring-data-commons 1.12.0.M1 Hopper release train.

Here's how my spring-data-neo4j-4.1.0.M1 jar dependency hierarchy looks like (and is 100% working).

[image]

This example pom (not neo4j specific) helped me get up and running.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/pom.xml#L35

also see:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/12/spring-data-release-train-hopper-m1-released

**UPDATE:** if you are using spring boot something like this (bare minimum pom)  should get you up and running. By specifying the `spring-data-releasetrain.version` with a value of `Hopper-M1` into your pom properites spring boot maven plugin will automatically bring down all the correct depedencies for spring-data-neo4j-4.1.0.M1

```
  <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<! --- omitted project info --> 

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Hopper-M1</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: I am not using spring boot. I tried to set spring-data-commons to 1.12.0.M1 but this does not help. I updated my question with POM and dependency hierarchy for spring-data-neo4j. What is strange is that when I look into Maven Dependencies I see that org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver is there.

Comment: @Cob well the exception you're getting is essentially a ClassNotFoundException. It cannot find the `HttpDriver` class. (which tells me you are having classpath issues) which stems from either missing or importing incorrect jars. Make sure you are cleaning your project.

Comment: @Cob if I had to guess I think that spring-data`-jpa` is downgrading some jars for you that spring-data-`neo4j` needs

Comment: It looks that spring-data-commons 1.12.0.M1 helped, but I did not clean my project. After doing this it is ok or maybe I should say better, because now I have problem like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/327 . Not with returning relationship, but node, but issue is exactly the same.

Comment: @Cobb that looks like it could be a bug that is a separate issue but if you can connect to the server now with the `HttpDriver` I think this issue is resolved :)

Comment: This line from the spring docs was helpful: 

Java Configuration
To configure the Driver programmatically, create a Configuration bean and pass it as the first argument to the SessionFactory constructor in your Spring configuration

Especially the part where it tells you to pass the config as a parameter in the session factory.